# how to add image back button on navigation bar in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

how to add an image as a back button to the left side of the navigation bar. I​ need a left arrow in the navigation bar. I need a solution in swift 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022780/uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-programmatically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom image for UINavigation Back Button in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912638/custom-image-for-uinavigation-back-button-in-ios-7)

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857833/adjust-position-of-custom-navigation-back-button/56859328#56859328

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
let yourBackImage = UIImage(named: "back_button_image")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = yourBackImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = yourBackImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "left_arrow_icon"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(didTapOnBack))   
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Drag "bar button item" to your navigation bar and set the desired image to that button.[image]